# Connecting to RDS Instance from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

This has been killing me all day.

I've set up Elastic Beanstalk, working fine.

Set up RDS, working fine and can access from my laptop.

But when i try to connect to the RDS from my ES application i get a timeout error.

Extra info is that i'm using a Laravel application, connecting to a MYSQL database. All of my environment variables have been loaded and accepted fine.

I'm almost certain it's a security groups setting, but the docs are so tremendously bad for AWS that i haven't got a clue what to do!

Any help?

Comment: Is your EB app in the same VPC as the RDS instance? What are your security group rules for the EB EC2 instances and the RDS instance?

Comment: The security group settings for your RDS instance should allow inbound from the security group that your elastic beanstalk instances are livin' in.

Comment: Yes, all in the same VPC. Think i've fixed it, but your suggestion of looking for the group for both RDS and ES helped! Adding answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer was to go to Services > VPC

Under the Security section, click Security groups.

Click the RDS group, then Inbound Rules.

Edit, then add a rule:

Select MYSQL, change the port, then the IP should be custom IP and type in the ID of your Elastic Beanstalk security group / groups (No idea why i have 2)

Comment: There are 2 groups because your EC2 instances will have one and your ELB will have one. Allow from the security group for the EC2.